# Creating a specific routing entry to access a controller within an Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to try and keep all my shopping cart processing within 1 controller within a separate "Area" in MVC2 project.

However, I need to expose 1 action in this controller to a URL that has been around for a long time and that URL does not include any reference to the area.

My area and controller are setup to deal with requests that look like this (Commerce is the Area):

```
http://www.abc.com/Commerce/Buy/Select
```

But the URL that I'm having to respond to is:

```
http://www.abc.com/quote/
```

Is it possible to create a one-off routing rule that would take care of this for me? I know I could create a Controller called "Quote" and sit it outside the Commerce area but I'd rather make use of routing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Quote", // Route name
            "/Quote/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { area="Commerce", controller = "Buy", action = "Quote", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 4 minutes!! I think this was a case of me asking before thinking! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, its easy as:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Quote", // Route name
            "Quote/", // URL with parameters
            new { area = "Commerce", controller = "Buy", action = "Select" } // Parameter default
            );
```